# How to use Automapper in ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

Edit #1 - Added a Unity Container to inject the mapper in the controller but facing the following error.

I have created `AutoMapperConfig.cs` file with the following code:

```
public static MapperConfiguration Configure() 
{
        MapperConfiguration mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<OrderDTO, Order>()
        });

        return mapperConfiguration;
}
```

Then in my `global.asax.cs` file under the `Application_start` method I added:

```
MapperConfiguration config = AutoMapperConfig.Configure();
IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterInstance(mapper); 
//or
//container.RegisterType<IMapper, Mapper>();
```

As per the documents I would do the following to use AutoMapper:

```
Order mapped_order = mapper.Map<Order>(orderdto);
```

Controller -

```
public class OrderController : Controller, IPersonalizable
    {
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public OrderController(IMapper mapper)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
        }
        // GET:
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
             Order mapped_order  = _mapper.Map<Order>(order);
        }
}
```

However, I am having trouble referencing "mapper" in my controller. I am missing some way to inject or reference it and I am struggling to understand how to do that.

Error -

````
IMapper No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.Activation path: 2) Injection of dependency IMapper into parameter mapper of constructor of type OrderController<br> &nbsp;1) Request for OrderController 
Suggestions: 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IMapper.
2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.
5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.```
````

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: I saw this but they're for .Net Core

Comment: The DI package works anywhere, you just have to integrate it in your app.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I tried DI using UnityContainer, can you tell where am I going wrong now?